# Fade background image moves in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am using the method outlined [here](http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/) to fade in a background image on hover of an element.

My codepen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqtjf

HTML:

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 219px;
    height: 218px;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/home-option-icon-off.png) no-repeat;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/home-option-icon-energy.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
}

div:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in Firefox (Mac) the background image of the span is not quite aligned with the background image of the span so when it fades in you can see a small movement (In the codepen the shift is vertical but in my project where the code is amongst a whole lot of other junk I actually had a horizontal shift). If you resize the Firefox window the problem is fixed.

A screencast of the effect can be seen here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/firefox-fadebg-problem.mp4
(View at 100% to see the problem which is subtle).

Any idea on whats causing this or how to fix?

Comment: On Firefox Windows, it seems I got a perfect behaviour.
Is it normal that you use a span with no text?

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know. The span is just to hold a separate background-image  to fade in. Its not pretty but CSS doesn't support transition on background-image itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a regression in how Firefox renders images with opacity animation, especially when the images has been resized with HTML  width/height attributes (usually by more than half).
The effect can be very subtle like a slight off-setting (~1 px) or a kind of antialiasing.

STR:
1. Open the testcase I joined
2. Move the mouse over the images to animate the opacity
3. Try at different zoom levels to observe the off-setting/antialiasing

WORKAROUND: adding "box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;" to images fixes the bad rendering.

source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745549

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same thing? My problem is using background-image on an element not an IMG tag. Adding "box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;" to the element doesn't help for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding the following to the images css.

`transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`